# Creating SPD 2010 workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Creating SPD 2010 workflow from a slide library.
[picture of Section called Tab 00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T5ew.png)

Hi All,

I have 10 sections in a report. Section 1 (Tab 00) is made up of 3 separate slides/records in the SP library. When a user is done editing a slide, they change the properties field called ‘Ready to Publish’ from 'No' to 'Yes'.

I’d like to write a workflow action in SPD 2010 that waits for all 3 records in Section 1  to equal ‘Yes’ then to send an email stating that the section 1 is complete.

As I’m trying to write this, I can only get the workflow to run on one document/slide at a time. So if a user selects 'Yes', then an email goes out that says the Section is complete, but the problem is only one slide of the 3 is complete. I’d like it to look through the entire library (query If record Section = Section 1 (Tab 00) and slides 001, 002, & 003 = Yes, then send email).

Thanks in advance for any help you all can give...I'm stumped.

Dave

Comment: i'll give this a try. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be achieved directly however you can use a second list which will have the section as title and separate columns for slides. Once user updates the slide mark as yes for the corresponding slide in second list. You can trigger email from second list on item updating workflow once all three  slides are marked to yes for that particular section.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. yes, I've created a second list that the first updates, slide by slide. appreciate the help.